# How do I get my custom email domain back from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, domain, g-suite-administrator

My uncle, who recently died, hooked me up with an Gmail account through his company, Radsoft. I don't have my uncle's password or his email or anything. My email was `******@radsoft.com`. It expired February 22 and now I can no longer receive emails from that account. This is a big problem because that is the email I used to sign up for my PayPal, my banking, my eBay, and pretty much everything else.

Now I need to get a confirmation email from PayPal to add my new bank account, but since I can't get the confirmation email there is nothing I can do.

Google has no customer service (that I know of) over the phone and they never answer my emails. They have a "fix the problem yourself" blog community thing, but I haven't had any luck finding a solution.

Is there a way I can renew this email even though I don't own this domain?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use email on a domain unless the domain-owner enables you to do that.

You need to go into your " paypal, my banking, my ebay, and pretty much everything else" and change your email address on those services to some other email address that you do have control of.